# Javascript closing button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to make a floating ads that will show at the bottom of the screen and this add will be invisible for 60s if anyone clicks the "close" button. I write this code but not working.

```html
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#close-fixedbox').on('click', function() {
         alert("Hello!");
    $('#fixedbox').hide(90);
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div id='fixedbox' style='width:100%;margin:auto;text-align:center;float:none;overflow:hidden;display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:0;z-index:999;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);'>

    <div>

    <a id='close-fixedbox' onclick='document.getElementById('fixedbox').style.display = 'none';' style='cursor:pointer;'>

    <img alt='close' src='http://www.latestbdnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/btn_close.gif' title='close button' style='vertical-align:center;'/>
    </a>
    </div>


    <div style='text-align:center;display:block;max-width:320px;height:auto;overflow:hidden;margin:auto'>


    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Mobile leaderboard -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"
         data-language="en">
         </ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: As a sidenote, this is probably a breach of Google's terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `'` for wrapping the `onclick` attribute **and** for the content of the script. Just replace one of them to double quotes (`"`).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#close-fixedbox').on('click', function() {
      alert("Hello!");
      $('#fixedbox').hide(90);
    });
  });
</script>

<div id='fixedbox' style='width:100%;margin:auto;text-align:center;float:none;overflow:hidden;display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:0;z-index:999;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);'>
  <div>
    <a id='close-fixedbox' onclick="document.getElementById('fixedbox').style.display = 'none';" style='cursor:pointer;'>
      <img alt='close' src='http://www.latestbdnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/btn_close.gif' title='close button' style='vertical-align:center;'/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style='text-align:center;display:block;max-width:320px;height:auto;overflow:hidden;margin:auto'>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Mobile leaderboard -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"
         data-language="en">
    </ins>
    <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery you added solves the problem.Otherwise you are having redundant code in your example triggering the close button both with jquery and javascript. Use any one.If your are using Javascript onClick then don't forget to enclose the action within proper quotes i.e use proper combination of `""` and `''`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#close-fixedbox').on('click', function() {
         alert("Hello!");
 $('#fixedbox').hide(90);
  });
 });
    </script>
 
    <div id='fixedbox' style='width:100%;margin:auto;text-align:center;float:none;overflow:hidden;display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:0;z-index:999;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);'>

    <div>

 <a id='close-fixedbox'  style='cursor:pointer;'>

 <img alt='close' src='http://www.latestbdnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/btn_close.gif' title='close button' style='vertical-align:center;'/>
    </a>
    </div>


    <div style='text-align:center;display:block;max-width:320px;height:auto;overflow:hidden;margin:auto'>
    
 
 <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Mobile leaderboard -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"
         data-language="en">
         </ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
     
        <div id='fixedbox' style='width:100%;margin:auto;text-align:center;float:none;overflow:hidden;display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:0;z-index:999;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);'>

        <div>

     <a id='close-fixedbox'  onclick="document.getElementById('fixedbox').style.display='none'" style='cursor:pointer;'>

     <img alt='close' src='http://www.latestbdnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/btn_close.gif' title='close button' style='vertical-align:center;'/>
        </a>
        </div>


        <div style='text-align:center;display:block;max-width:320px;height:auto;overflow:hidden;margin:auto'>
        
     
     <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Mobile leaderboard -->
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
             data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
             data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"
             data-language="en">
             </ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @JacquesMarais When I wrote the answer jquery was missing. The person editing the code added that after I wrote my answer

Comment: Oh I didn't see that, sorry.

Comment: tnx everyone :) you guys helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use single quotes in your JavaScript if the attribute has single quotes:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#close-fixedbox').on('click', function() {
      alert("Hello!");
      $('#fixedbox').hide(90);
    });
  });
</script>

<div id='fixedbox' style='width:100%;margin:auto;text-align:center;float:none;overflow:hidden;display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:0;z-index:999;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);'>
  <div>
    <a id='close-fixedbox' onclick="document.getElementById('fixedbox').style.display = 'none';" style='cursor:pointer;'>

      <img alt='close' src='http://www.latestbdnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/btn_close.gif' title='close button' style='vertical-align:center;'/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style='text-align:center;display:block;max-width:320px;height:auto;overflow:hidden;margin:auto'>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Mobile leaderboard -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXX"
         data-language="en">
    </ins>
    <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code causing a Javascript error, you need to remove the inline event from the anchor tag, it should seem as following:

```
<a id='close-fixedbox' style='cursor:pointer;'>
```

jQuery hide function will set display attribute to *none*, so you don't need to set it explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you,  everyone for you kind reply and your efforts. I solved it by myself . I just added jquery link at top of that code and it starts working .

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When asking a jQuery question, we normally assume that you've at least already included the jQuery library.

Comment: @Sparky i'm extreamly sorry :( that was a huge mistake